# Отображение коллекции объектов внутри модели

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Есть модель такого вида:

```
 public class User
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public IList<Request> Requests { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Requests= new List<Request>();
    }
}
```

И соответственно `Request`:

```
public class Request
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string SitemapUrl { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan TimeRequest { get; set; }
}
```

Вопрос: Как развернуть `List<Request>` внутри представления? Вот мой класс `View`:

```
@model  IEnumerable<Project.Models.User>

<div>
    <h3>Users</h3>
    <table>
        <tr class="header"><td><p>Url</p></td>
        </tr>
        @foreach(var b in Model)
        {
    <tr>
        <td><p>@b.SitemapUrl</p></td> // Источник проблемы
        <td><p>@b.TimeRequest</p></td>
    </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по

```
@model  IEnumerable<Project.Models.User>
```

в представление передаётся коллекция пользователей.

У класса `User` нет свойств `SitemapUrl` и `TimeRequest`.

У каждого юзера есть вложенный список с реквестами. Нужно пройтись по этому списку.
Например, так:

```
@foreach (var user in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@string.Join(" ", user.Requests.Select(r => r.SitemapUrl))</td>
        <td>@string.Join(" ", user.Requests.Select(r => r.TimeRequest))</td>                    
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, отличное решение